# How far off do I need to make my symmetrical society so that you can tell that its not

Tags: society

My space faring crew, after encountering a planet of people that [can walk on the walls](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/183452/how-would-houses-change-if-we-could-walk-on-the-walls), has now encounter a world that is nearly symmetrical in all aspects. But they actually aren't, and everything is slightly off. Not enough that you can say 'hah, your nose is where your eye should be', but enough where you can say 'your face looks a little off'. This won't be limited just to faces, but to houses, cars, skyscrapers, fences, and basically everything. I want it to be off enough that you get a weird vibe, but anything short of measuring and you can't tell that it's not symmetrical.

So, how far off do I need to make things so it's off just enough to feel weird?

Comment: I think an (almost) perfectly symmetrical person would look "off" enough in and of itself.

Comment: @F1Krazy Isn't as close to a perfectly symmetrical face how beauty has been judged in the past?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an answer here. The question is about the subjective nature of an "off" feeling. This depends on eacht person, so no one answer can be given. Isn't it enough to describe the feeling?

Comment: @Trioxidane I think when a movies audio is slightly out of sync and the difference changes theres an weird off feeling but i dont know what the symmetry visual version of that would be.

Comment: @Orochi: Yes, that's true. (And I don't get it why you say "in the past". In what country isn't that still the case?) But F1Krazy's point is that *nobody* is perfectly symmetrical. Indeed, if you take a photo and manipulate it to create a perfectly symmetrical face it will indeed feel just a little strange.

Comment: @AlexP I dont know why I said "in the past" either lol. I forgot to mention the world of body building is all about having a symmetrical body, no one can ever have one down to every angle and measurement but they live to achieve that symmetry.

Comment: I don't usually gripe about queries being opinion based, but this one is just off enough to get a close vote.

Comment: I have never seen a perfectly symmetrical house, or car, or skyscraper. And I like to photograph buildings... Not even when the building intentionally strives to send a feeling of severe symmetry; consider for example the Taj Mahal, where despairingly exact symmetry is one of the essential features of the design, and [consider closely the flowery arabesque](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Taj_Mahal_(Edited).jpeg) (not to mention the [calligraphic text](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Facade_of_Taj_Mahal_(4718894898).jpg)) above the main entrance vault.

Comment: @AlexP Thats true at first I thought some buildings were but I thought due to structural issues and materials it could never be perfect, some other creative arts try to achieve symmetry and in nature there are symmetrical fractal patterns we find beautiful, maybe because they are simple to read.

Comment: @AlexP all this talk of symmetry started making me think I might like supersymmetry theory but then I remembered the stupid names adding an S before a particle name, then I realised the letter S isnt even a symmetric shape, then I realised you already pointed out un symmetrical text already lol.

Comment: @Orochi: The Latin capital letter S has twofold rotational symmetry, i.e., a rotation by 180° will leave it unchanged... Whether the symmetry is more or less perfect depends on the font. Typically, Roman (also known as Antiqua, e.g., Times) fonts introduce line variations and serifs which subtly break the symmetry of letters such as A, B, C, D, E, M, N, O, S, U, V, W, X, Y and Z; Grotesque (e.g., Helvetica) fonts on the contrary use uniform lines and no serifs, emphasizing the symmetry of those letters.

Comment: @AlexP I meant its not symmetrical if divided down the centre vertically or horizontally , if using our format of writing in vertically stacked horizontal lines, so letters like O and X can be mirror imaged, I just thought a truly symmetric society would have a fully symmetrical writing system and symbols.

Comment: @Orochi: Reflectional symmetry is just one [form of symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry). Symmetry can also be rotational, translational, helical, glide reflectional and rotoreflectional. The basic idea is that a geometrical figure possesses some sort of symmetry if there is a reflection, rotation, translation or combination operation which leaves it unchanged. This is the meaning of the word "symmetry" when we say for example that crystals are symmetrical; they are not at all always reflectionally symmetrical.

Answer (score 3):

#### Perfect symmetry is more upsetting than subtle imperfections

Errors in symmetry are common, and to be expected in the real world;

[image] [image]

For example, in faces: (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facial_symmetry) "While symmetrical faces (leftmost image) are perceived to be attractive, completely symmetric faces (a and b) are disconcerting and are not perceived as normal."

Regarding homes, fences, offices, etc, slightly asymmetrical is par for the course. And once you start spotting tiny imperfections your own home-handyman mistakes, you spot it in professional work too. Spotting imperfections is like spotting [Bad Kerning](https://xkcd.com/1015/), once you see it, you'll never be able to unsee it. If you can't see it, you'll look harder.

Big skyscrapers may be hard to detect with the naked eye, but they are never perfectly symmetrical. They're subtly blown sideways in the wind, parts expand in the heat and shrink in the shade. Even during construction a team will be responsible for keeping things plumb between the first and second steelworks teams, subtly correcting for imperfections of fractions of a degree, the constant refinement of "up" results in a subtle, barely perceivable "snaking" of skyscrapers.

Comment: Those images look like a flattened out skin and a cropped skin for a 3D model, they dont look like a frontal view of a face.